# Ember, rendering a nested collection of models asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

*Disclaimer: very ember newbie here so maybe what I'm asking is too basic but I don't find any explanation for this in the web*

I have a parent object *Report* which contains a collection of *Chart* objects.

When I load the URL `/api/reports/001/charts`, the *report 001* is requested to the API, then all the *charts* belonging to this *report*, then everything is rendered and .. seconds latter the page is shown to the User.

Like this:

[image]

What I'm trying is to offer a more progressive rendering:

1. The *report* is loaded from the API
2. The *report* is shown to the User with the *chart* elements with a *loading* spinner
3. Every *chart* is requested to the API individually
4. Every *chart* is show to the User individually

Steps 3 and 4 happen in parallel independent for each *chart*.

Something like this:

[image]

Of course I don't want anyone to come to me with a full solution, I'm looking more for orientation or maybe some link to where I can find inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

We are doing something similar to this on our dashboard. In the route we load the users dashboard which contains a list of widgets and their position. Then in the dashboard template we render components for each widget, something like this.

```
{{#each widgets as |widget|}}
  {{component widget.type widget}}
{{/each}}
```

Then by passing the widget instance (which has it's own custom settings) to the component we can then fetch the relevant data and display it. Each widget can also have it's own "spinner" to tell the user that it's still loading.

If I assume that your case is a bit simpler since you are only showing charts and probably by an id of some sort you could probably get away without using the component-helper and directly referencing your chart component.

```
{{#each charts as |chart|}}
  {{report-chart chart.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi @yorbro your addon looks very promising, can you create a proper answer with your proposition?

Comment: @karl-johan-sjögren moving the _charts_ loading functionality to a Component is a very good idea, I have been working with that one but I started to find issues. Looks like Ember doesn't like this approach specially because to make it work I have to [load the Models into the Component code](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/should-ember-components-load-data/4218) and things (helpers, templates) started to fail. I am gonna still trying, I just wanted to share the difficulties I'm finding.

Comment: Yes loading data in a component isn't optimal but in some cases it's the only viable way unless you start messing with subroutes (which won't help if you want more then one chart). To get around the problem with things not being ready you could use the addon @yorbro suggested or simply do it yourself with a property that waits for the promise to complete. Just don't have it trying to render stuff before your data is ready.

Comment: Still not able to make this work. Now the problem is that the `Component` renders before the data is loaded so all the internal _partials_ in the _Component's templates_ fail. I have been checking [Controller life cycle](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=ember+component+life+cicle&btnG=Buscar+con+Google&aq=0&aqi=g3g-s1&aql=&oq=delicious+on+&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) but it is nothing clear for me. Moving the question to [discuss.emberjs.com thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/rendering-a-hasmany-relation-asynchronously/9313)